# Storing semi persistant data for a SPA

Tags: rest, vue.js, single-page-application

I have a SPA website set up with a REST API. One of the issues I have come up against is how to access data unrelated to the resource being requested. Specifically, accessing the users account details so I can do things like hide admin actions when the user is not an admin.

I have an api endpoint that can get all this data so the simplest solution would be to on every page load request the profile api as well as the resource actually being accessed. This seems a little wasteful to be constantly requesting a resource that rarely changes.

Another option would be to store this data in local storage so it only has to be requested once but then I have the issue where the user updates their username or settings on one device and then the other one is left with outdated data in local storage.

I thought vuex might be able to persist this data when clicking on links and navigating to different pages but it seems like the data gets lost when the page changes.

From what I understand graphql would solve this problem by allowing the initial request to get the user data along with the other data. I'm not really sure how much more efficient this is than 2 requests and rewriting my whole api probably isn't the best solution to this.

Are there any well known solutions to this problem or is one of the options I have come up with the best way to handle this?

Comment: *I thought vuex might be able to persist this data when clicking on links and navigating to different pages but it seems like the data gets lost when the page changes.*. Here, you need something like this: [https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate)

Comment: Have you tried storing you data on the root and then accessing with this.$root.$data?